# python: plotting numbers as a custom range

Tags: python, average

I'm not sure how to actually word it, but basically want i want to do is make 3 sets of number to be equivalent to the range of 0 to 10 so i that i can call it later.

for example, if i have the numbers 2, 4, and 9, i want it so that 2 represents 0, 4 as 5, and 9 as 10. that way say if i write a command that says like "call for a number that represents 2.5", then it gives me like 3. for more examples:

0=2, 2.5=3, 5=4, 7.5=6.5, 10=9

And i want it so that after i have set these numbers, i can just call from within this custom range of 2-9 by just saying which part of the scale i want (like I want the value that represents 1.25). Is there a way to do something like this in Python...?

PS: i'm sorry if a question like this already exists, I just don't know what this sort of thing is called.

EDIT: Just so you understand more of what i want to do, i'm trying to set this thing up as a script in Maya (3d program), and I would have a set of curves. Right now I have a script written to smooth out jagged curves by taking averages of 3 points and replacing that average to the middle number. But what I want to do is rather than taking just an average, is to be able to have an input of a value from 0-10 so it controls how much the curve smooths out. so if i have a curve where i have say 2 6 and 4 on Y, instead of making the middle number 3.667 (the average of the three values), I would want it to be at like 4 or 3.25, or anything other than the average. Essentially I want just a 0-10 system that controls how much this number decreases. I hope this makes sense.......

Comment: It appears you're looking for [Curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.... but yes technically what i am asking for is no longer "linear"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any three points, you can [define a quadratic curve that fits them](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~lms/research/curvefitting.html).

So for example, [modifying code from this VB helper page](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_find_quadratic_curve.html), you get

```
def fit(p1, p2, p3):
    """Return the quadratic function that fits the three points p1, p2, p3,
    each defined as a tuple of (x,y) coordinates"""
    a = ((p2[1]-p1[1])*(p1[0]-p3[0]) + (p3[1]-p1[1])*(p2[0]-p1[0])) / \
        ((p1[0]-p3[0])*(p2[0]**2-p1[0]**2) + (p2[0]-p1[0])*(p3[0]**2-p1[0]**2))
    b = ((p2[1]-p1[1]) - a*(p2[0]**2 - p1[0]**2)) / (p2[0]-p1[0])
    c = p1[1] - a*p1[0]**2 - b*p1[0]
    return lambda x: a*x**2 + b*x + c
```

will give you a function that you can use (in Python 3) as follows:

```
>>> f = fit((0,2), (5,4), (10,9))
>>> f(2)
2.44
>>> f(100)
612.0
>>> f(4)
3.36
>>> f(5)
4.0
>>> f(9)
7.760000000000001
```

In Python 2, you need to call it with floats explicitly:

```
>>> f = fit((0.0,2.0), (5.0,4.0), (10.0,9.0))
```

Comment: It appears your solution answers his issue better than the original problem he presented us... +1

Comment: okay, so apparently my question is way more difficult than i thought it would be. I have never learned how to deal with "curves" before in Python (my knowledge is very basic).

so I tried to use this code that you've written, but it doesn't seem to be working... no matter what I plugin to the f(x) part, it just gives me a result of 2. am I using it incorrectly?

then again it may be because i'm using Maya as a Python interpreter(or whatever it's called)...

Comment: That is some ugly code! Scipy has it implemented: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: @user3696118: As I wrote, on Python 2, you need to pass `float`s to it explicitly.

Comment: @Davidmh: Well, that's the mathematical equations you need for doing it by hand (of course I could have used some new variable names like `x1` and `y2` for clarity). I doubt that Maya has included scipy in their Python implementation...

Comment: @TimPietzcker right, I missed he was in Maya, I just got hurt in pyhtonism :). It can be installed, though: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Programming/Adding-Python-modules-scipy-numpy/td-p/4304367

Comment: Okay, well I just re-tried the Python 2 version that you wrote, and it seems to work. So are these values based on like a curve that's created similar to something like this?:

http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/05/03/reverse-engineering-quadratic-bezier-curves/

Comment: @user3696118: Did you read the Wikipedia article I linked? There are infinitely many ways to fit a curve through three points; there is exactly one quadratic curve that fits.

Comment: sorry about that, I only skimmed it due to the mass response I was getting for this question.

I read a bit more, and I sort of understand what's going on. And since what you wrote is like you said a modified version of this VB Helper page, I'll try to figure it out. I'm still not sure what this / \ thing is in the fourth line, so hopefully I can figure it out.

Thank you so much for all your support

Comment: The backslash is needed to escape the newline after it - that equation is so long that I wanted to break it up into two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to store pairs of data, like

```
x = {0:2, 2.5:3, 5:4, 7.5:6.5, 10:9}
```

Then just by using the dictionary's key you can get the value you want.

```
>>> x[0]
2
```

Comment: THank you for your prompt reply. But my concern for your suggestion is then how do i call for a number that is equivalent to say 1.5? Because all that is is just a list of pairs of data, it does not function as a "range" like I've mentioned...

Comment: @user3696118 I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. You want a number to represent a scaled model, but it's not linear and how it's modeled is unclear. Do you have a custom curve that you want to model?

Comment: i guess you can say that.... i've added more info in my original post, perhaps that will give you a more clear idea of what i want to do... and see if its even possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to generate the "range" points you need:

```
def range_(lst, size):
    i = 0.0
    while i < size:
        i += size/float(len(size))
        yield i
```

Then you can zip the results of this function with the original list like so:

```
def range_(lst, size):
    i = 0.0
    while i <= size:
        yield i
        i += size/float(len(lst)-1)

vals = [2,3,4,6]

res = dict(zip(range_(vals,10),vals))

print res
```

This gives:

```
{0.0: 2, 3.3333333333333335: 3, 10.0: 6, 6.666666666666667: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from random import random
from math import ceil


def get_number(num):
  return ceil(random() * 10 * num)/10

def return_set():
  my_set = []
  add_up_to_me = 10.0
  for i in range(0,2):
   num = get_number(add_up_to_me)
   add_up_to_me -= num
   my_set.append(num)
  my_set.append((add_up_to_me * 10)/10)
  return my_set

correlate = {}

for i,j in zip(return_set(),return_set()):
  correlate[i] = j

print correlate
```

Comment: If you want to go by say 100ths instead of tenths, change the `return ceil(random() *10 * num)/10` to `return ceil(random() * 100 * num)/100` and so on and so forth